# Is the 's' or the 'c' silent on scent?

Tags: silent-letter

Which of the first two letters on the word 'scent' is silent?

- if 's' is silent, the word cent is pronounced like we pronounce 'scent'
- if the 'c' is silent, the word is still pronounced the same, right?

So, which one of the letters is silent?

Comment: The same one as in _science_, I guess. Is there really any situation in which the answer to this question would actually matter? Or is there any way the answer to this question could actually be verified? In the following string of characters, I removed one: `SRTWN`. Did I remove a B, or did I remove an M?

Comment: For the correct pronunciation, it does not matter. However, it is still interesting that the c in scent may be regarded as silent, but not the s in scandal.

Comment: Maybe the easiest is not to regard any of them as silent, the Zen way out of this question :)

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/193549/18195

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "c" is silent when preceded by an "s" followed by an 'e' or an 'i' at the beginning of a word.
Found this on a site which had rules on silent letters. Authenticity is not known, but it sounds correct.

Comment: What would change if it was the _s_ that was silent? Or if actually, _neither_ of the two were silent?

Comment: Will need some expert advice on this one. Had 'c' not been silent, could it have added a 'k' sound to it ? like 's-k-ience', maybe ?

Comment: Why? Normally, the _c_ is pronounced as an _s_ sound before an _i_, so why would that be different now? Is the second _s_ in _lass_ (or the one letter shorter word) pronounced or not? Is the first one? Are they both pronounced? _And does it matter?_

Comment: i thought more of words like, acute, actual, acrobat etc.

Comment: I don't know why, but my instincts also tell me it's the "c" that is silent, and not the "s".

Comment: Scintillating !

Answer (score 6):

"Sc" can be a digraph (two letters combined to make one sound) or a consonant blend (two letters combined that make two sounds). This is why you hear one sound with the "sc" in "science" or "sent," and you hear two sounds with the "sc" in "scare." I would argue that neither is silent; it's used as a consonant digraph to make one sound.

Comment: +1 This is a perfectly reasonable synchronic analysis, although diachronically I think it's best to say it's the 'c' that is silent.  The word was originally spelled 'sent' and the 'c' was added at a later date without changing the pronunciation.

Comment: I also take it as a digraph, analogous to scene, scintillate, scion, etc. I don't follow the historical argument for silent 'c': people added a 'c' relatively late, therefore they weren't treating 'sc' as a digraph?

Comment: From a historical perspective, in words like *scene* and *scintillate*, the ‹c› originally represented a /k/ sound which is no longer pronounced, so it makes sense to think of it as silent.  If you ignore that and look only at the sound-letter correspondence, then you can conclude ‹sc› is pronounced /s/, and then working from the other direction, you can say the same thing of ‹sc› in *scent*.  That's a perfectly fine conclusion―but I don't think it's a *historical* conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=scent&allowed_in_frame=0):

> late 14c., sent "to find the scent of," from Old French sentir "to feel, smell,  touch, taste; realize, perceive; make love to," from Latin sentire " to feel, perceive,sense, discern, hear, see" (see sense (n.)).
>
> Originally a hunting term. The -c- appeared 17c., perhaps by influence of  ascent, descent, etc., or by influence of science. This was a tendency in early Modern English, also in scythe and for a time threatening to make scite and scituate.

This implies that the "c" is silent as the word was originally "sent". The addition of the "c" was likely to normalize it with words such as "science"; however, in Anglo-Latin, "c" is pronounced as "s" before front vowels e, æ, œ, i, y (It's pronounced as "sh" when not initial, before semivowel i and e). This would imply that it's actually the "s" that is silent as a result of palatalization.

In a way, both answers are correct, but a silent "c" is a better answer due to the origin of the word.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sent_1), [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/scent_1) and [here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cent_1), the words sent, cent, and scent are pronounced in exactly the same way, namely as [sent]. Hence, you may regard the "s" or the "c" as being silent in the sense that it does not modify the pronunciation. However, if you leave out either "s" or "c", the other is of course not silent.

Edit: I just discovered a much older discussion of this question on ELU [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193548/in-the-word-scent-is-the-s-or-the-c-silent).

Comment: And can't the _s_ be considered silent for the same reason?

Comment: Exactly, I just updated my answer.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake: what if we consider _neither_ of them silent? The same issue arises in _lass_: is any of those _s_'s silent?

Comment: That is also OK in this case, because c and s are both pronounced as [s]. Similarly, the double-s in lass is also pronounced like a single s, namely [s].

Comment: So I guess you have a point when you say that the question may not make much sense.

Answer (score -3):

If the S is silent and not the C then it would be pronounced, "kent" instead of cent. The reason why is that the C isn't silent if the S is silent. So the C is silent.

Comment: "Cent" is not pronounced "kent", so I'm not sure of this.